# Loading specific SAPUI5 Business Suite not possible

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

i have a question, i dont really get it.. because i cant find anything to this..
First of all my UI5 Version 1.71 (there is also no hint if a specific version is required for the icons.)

My problem is, that only some of the business suite icons are displayed or even are loaded..

for example how i get the icons:

```
const fonts = [{
                fontFamily: "BusinessSuiteInAppSymbols",
                fontURI: sap.ui.require.toUrl("sap/ushell/themes/base/fonts/")
            }];

            fonts.forEach(oFont => {
                IconPool.registerFont(oFont);
            });
```

it is okay, it will be registerd and some of the icons are available for example (`sap-icon://BusinessSuiteInAppSymbols/icon-truck-load`)

but anyway some of them are not (`sap-icon://BusinessSuiteInAppSymbols/icon-stock-warehouse`) i mean why? there is no information about this on the icon page, why this should not displayed or loaded ? or i am blind?

since the page for the icon says there are 338 Icons  [image: 338]

but if i check how much items i loaded there are 287, i mean why? i cant find anything related to this
[image]

Comment: The icon has neither tags nor categories. Maybe this really is a version issue?

Comment: @Marc yeah like the Anwser below.. it is. But anyway I cant find a way to change the version if I call directly the icon-explorer. Only way I found go trough the sdk -> change the version and navigate to the tools and than click on the icon-explorer.. kinda meh but it works! thanks you also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icons delivered with UI5 depend indeed on the version. Therefore, if you want to check which icon is available for a specific UI5 version you should use the versioned demo kit to get the exact details for the version you are using.

You wrote you are using UI5 version 1.71. If you use now [the Icon Explorer URL for SAPUI5 1.71.43](https://ui5.sap.com/1.71.43/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/iconExplorer/webapp/index.html#/overview/BusinessSuiteInAppSymbols/) you can see that there are only 300 icons in (and icon-stock-warehouse is not part of it).

Comment: Thanks buddy ! But where I can change the version? I always call https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/iconExplorer/webapp/index.html

Comment: The easiest way is to use the version switcher (Button "Change version in the upper right corner) in the demo kit (e.g. https://ui5.sap.com or in your chase https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com) and navigate then to the icon explorer. 
But as it follows always the exact same pattern you can easily adjust the URL yourself by adding the exact version to the URL after the domain name like this https://ui5.sap.com/1.71.43/...). 
See also the UI5 documentation here: https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f021426f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070